# How to make "#!" portable to different systems which have python installed at different locations?

Tags: python, shebang

My script has this at the first line:

#!/usr/bin/python3.6

But in different system python3.6 is installed at different locations, such as:

```
/user/bin/python3.6
/tools/bin/python3.6
/user/local/bin/python3.6
```

How can I make my script good at the these 3 systems?

Comment: Why is this tagged "bash"? Bash isn't involved in parsing the shebang -- that's done by your OS kernel. (_Strictly_, some shells will try to do it themselves as a fallback if the OS reports a failure in the `execve()` syscall or its local equivalent, but it's the operating system kernel's job; the shell implementations, when/where they exist, are just as a fallback/workaround for OS bugs).

Comment: Shebangs are not meant to provide portability. They are instructions to the local kernel as to where the interpreter is located. It can and should be set as appropriate at installation time, rather than given a one-size-fits-all value when the script is written.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You’re correct but I’ve re-tagged this as [tag:shell] nonetheless, since the shebang line is conceptually linked to the shell. The fact that the shell forwards this to the OS (IIRC via `execve`?) is something few people realise, and also doesn’t affect this question.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Maybe we should then emphasize that it's *not* something the shell uses itself.

Comment: The shell doesn't forward anything; the OS itself looks at the first few bytes of an executable to see what its format is. The bytes `#!` are interpreted as introducing a path to use as an interpreter. The shell's only involvement is when the OS decides it can't execute the file, at which point the shell may try something else. (`bash`, for example, forks itself to execute the file as a `bash` script; othershells assume the default system shell should be used.)

Comment: @chepner You convinced me.

Answer (score 3):

There are broadly two alternatives:

1. Don’t hard-code the path; instead, use `env` to determine the path:

   ```sh
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   ```
2. Or don’t write scripts with a shebang line *at all*; instead, create a proper package with a setuptools installer, and [instruct setuptools to create an executable file](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html) with the proper interpreter set for the target system.

For anything that’s more than a quick & dirty script, or a script purely intended for local consumption, the second choice is more maintainable, and constitutes the “proper” way of doing this.

Comment: #2 is definitely preferable; the version of Python your script expects may not be the primary version of Python specified by the user's environment.